# Compilador Less CSS in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, less

The script of [Less css](http://lesscss.org/) is very good. However I would like to reduce the amount of amount of procesesos in html. Since I have the Jquery in the same html, you can generate all CSS. from files less.

I'm looking for a way to render files less in Jquery. Ahy some way to climb the scriptlet of LESS in JQuery?

Comment: It is hard to understand what your question is, you may want to consider rephrasing it.

Comment: So sorry! for my English ... I think I'll edit the question... ok!!

Comment: What is your IDE? If you're using Visual Studio, I highly suggest using [Chirpy](http://chirpy.codeplex.com) (no affiliation). You can mash and minify your CSS and your JS, and it will also process your LESS and SASS as well as CoffeeScript.

Comment: What you're asking for doesn't really make sense. `jQuery` isn't a LESS compiler, there's no reason for it to be a LESS compiler (since LESS already has one), and there's no performance advantage to be gained by making it one if you're bundling JavaScript libraries (as you should.)

Comment: I want to avoid compiling the creation of CSS as such, ie not made from Server but the user or browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compilers for less

- [Crunch](http://crunchapp.net/)
- [CodeKit](http://incident57.com/codekit/)
- [Simpleless](http://wearekiss.com/simpless)

Answer (score 0):

JQuery will likely only slow less rendering process as it would have to be completely rewritten for jQuery.

If you want more speed I would recommend finding a less **compiler** like [Less.app](http://incident57.com/less/) is for Mac OS X. This will also make your website still function without javascript.

Please list alternatives to [Less.app](http://incident57.com/less/) in comments if you know of any.

Comment: [CodeKit](http://incident57.com/codekit/) is one. Preprocessing with `lessc` is another option that should work anywhere Node.js does. Then there's the various on-demand server-side renderers like [Cassette](http://getcassette.net/) for ASP.NET, [django-css](https://github.com/dziegler/django-css#readme) for Django. Not sure what would be good for Rails, they seem to favour SASS and (ugh) Compass.

Comment: @Inerdial thanks. Note to all though, on command line the Ruby version has been phased out, so `lessc` is the Node.js version for which there are [instructions](http://lesscss.org/#-server-side-usage)